# How to serve JSON object from Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson-databind

I have a REST API (implemented with spring boot) that should be able to handle serving both XML and JSON. All of my data models are able to be returned as both XML and JSON, but one of them only returns XML, even when I specify "Accept application/json" in the headers in postman.

This is an example of one of the ones that works:
[image: Document model object works in XML and JSON]

Here is the one that doesnt:
[image: ServiceError model object only returns in XML]

As you can see both of them share the same accessors and tags for jackson, yet they have different behaviors. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Hard to say. Sure, there is not an "old version" (only XML) of `ServiceError` on the classpath ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Im not sure, but when I do echo %CLASSPATH% in the command prompt I dont see a reference to ServiceError

Comment: I guess it is `<packaging>jar</packaging>`, so all is in one fat JAR. Maybe there are more than one `ServiceError` in ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I am publishing the jar on an internal maven repository and referencing it through that, so Im not sure if its possible to have multiple ServiceErrors. Even in production on a clean VM the same issue reproduces.

Comment: @PeterMmm I found a line of code that was explicitly setting it to accept xml so I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your help though!